# My Neural Network is only learning some data sets

Tags: c++, neural-network

I've created the following NN that should be learning based on back propagation.

I've peiced it together from a lot of reading and a bunch of different tutorials.

To test, I've tried giving it the XOR problem. Each data set is 2 inputs and 2 outputs. The two inputs are both either a `1` or `0`, and the two outputs should indicate whether a `0` should be output (the first output) or a `1` should be output (the second output).

What's happening when I give it the following data:

```
___________________________________________________________________________
| Input 1 | Input 2 | Expected 1 | Expected 2 | NN Output 1 | NN Output 2 |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    0    |    1    |     1      |     0      |    0.49     |    0.50     |
|    1    |    0    |     1      |     0      |    0.98     |    0.01     |
|    1    |    1    |     0      |     1      |    0.01     |    0.98     |
|    0    |    0    |     0      |     1      |    0.49     |    0.50     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is hopefully clear in the above is that for two of the problems given it; it's sort of worked, assuming there's a margin of error, getting within 0.01 of the answer is pretty good.

But for the other two answers, it's way off. Sure a step-function would result correctly, but it's basically saying there's a 50/50 split.

This is with 100,000 epochs and a learning rate of `0.03` and what you see above was the actual training data.

If I increase the learning rate to `0.9`; the results are different but also make me question things:

```
___________________________________________________________________________
| Input 1 | Input 2 | Expected 1 | Expected 2 | NN Output 1 | NN Output 2 |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    0    |    1    |     1      |     0      |    0.99     |    0.00     |
|    1    |    0    |     1      |     0      |    0.99     |    0.00     |
|    1    |    1    |     0      |     1      |    0.49     |    0.99     |
|    0    |    0    |     0      |     1      |    0.00     |    0.99     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Much better; but there's still the weird output for the `1,1` input.

My code is fairly short, here below. It's the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

class RandomGenerator
{
public:
    RandomGenerator(const double min, const double max)
    :
        m_ran(),
        m_twister(m_ran()),
        m_distrib(min,max)
    {

    }

    double operator()(void) { return m_distrib(m_twister); }

private:
    std::random_device                      m_ran;
    std::mt19937_64                         m_twister;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double>  m_distrib;
} randGen(-2,2);

double sigmoid(const double x)
{
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + std::exp(-x));
}

double softplus(const double x)
{
    return std::log(1.0 + std::exp(x));
}

double step(const double x)
{
    return x > 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

template<int NumInputs, double(*ActivationFunction)(const double)>
class Neuron
{
public:

    void SetInput(const std::size_t index, const double value)
    {
        m_inputsAndWeights[index].value = value;
    }

    double GetInput(const std::size_t index) const { return m_inputsAndWeights[index].value; }

    void SetWeight(const std::size_t index, const double weight)
    {
        m_inputsAndWeights[index].weight = weight;
    }

    double GetWeight(const std::size_t index) const { return m_inputsAndWeights[index].weight; }

    void SetBiasWeight(const double weight) { m_biasWeight = weight; }
    double GetBiasWeight() const { return m_biasWeight; }

    double GetOutput() const
    {
        double output = 0;
        for(const auto& p : m_inputsAndWeights)
            output += p.value * p.weight;
        output += 1.0 * m_biasWeight;
        return ActivationFunction(output);
    }

private:
    struct DataPair
    {
        double value;
        double weight;
    };

    std::array<DataPair,NumInputs> m_inputsAndWeights;
    double m_biasWeight;
};

template<std::size_t NumInputs, std::size_t NumOutputs>
class NeuralNetwork
{
public:
    static constexpr NumHidden() { return (NumInputs+NumOutputs) / 2; }

    SetInputs(std::array<double,NumInputs> inputData)
    {
        for(auto& i : m_hiddenNeurons)
        {
            for(auto index = 0; index < inputData.size(); ++index)
                i.SetInput(index,inputData[index]);
        }
    }

    std::array<double,NumOutputs> GetOutputs() const
    {
        std::array<double,NumOutputs> outputs;
        for(auto i = 0; i < NumOutputs; ++i)
        {
            outputs[i] = m_outputNeurons[i].GetOutput();
        }
        return outputs;
    }

    void PassForward(std::array<double,NumInputs> inputData)
    {
        SetInputs(inputData);
        for(auto i = 0; i < NumHidden(); ++i)
        {
            for(auto& o : m_outputNeurons)
            {
                o.SetInput(i,m_hiddenNeurons[i].GetOutput());
            }
        }
    }

    void Train(std::vector<std::array<double,NumInputs>> trainingData,
               std::vector<std::array<double,NumOutputs>> targetData,
               double learningRate, std::size_t numEpochs)
    {
        for(auto& h : m_hiddenNeurons)
        {
            for(auto i = 0; i < NumInputs; ++i)
                h.SetWeight(i,randGen());
            h.SetBiasWeight(randGen());
        }
        for(auto& o : m_outputNeurons)
        {
            for(auto h = 0; h < NumHidden(); ++h)
                o.SetWeight(h,randGen());
            o.SetBiasWeight(randGen());
        }

        for(std::size_t e = 0; e < numEpochs; ++e)
        {
            for(std::size_t dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < trainingData.size(); ++dataIndex)
            {
                PassForward(trainingData[dataIndex]);

                std::array<double,NumHidden()+1> deltaHidden;
                std::array<double,NumOutputs> deltaOutput;

                for(auto i = 0; i < NumOutputs; ++i)
                {
                    auto output = m_outputNeurons[i].GetOutput();
                    deltaOutput[i] = output * (1.0 - output) * (targetData[dataIndex][i] - output);
                }
                for(auto i = 0; i < NumHidden(); ++i)
                {
                    double error = 0;
                    for(auto j = 0; j < NumOutputs; ++j)
                    {
                        error += m_outputNeurons[j].GetWeight(i) * deltaOutput[j];
                    }
                    auto output = m_hiddenNeurons[i].GetOutput();
                    deltaHidden[i] = output * (1.0 - output) * error;
                }
                for(auto i = 0; i < NumOutputs; ++i)
                {
                    for(auto j = 0; j < NumHidden(); ++j)
                    {
                        auto currentWeight = m_outputNeurons[i].GetWeight(j);
                        m_outputNeurons[i].SetWeight(j,currentWeight + learningRate * deltaOutput[i] * m_hiddenNeurons[j].GetOutput());
                    }
                    auto currentWeight = m_outputNeurons[i].GetBiasWeight();
                    m_outputNeurons[i].SetBiasWeight(currentWeight + learningRate * deltaOutput[i] * (1.0*currentWeight));
                }
                for(auto i = 0; i < NumHidden(); ++i)
                {
                    for(auto j = 0; j < NumInputs; ++j)
                    {
                        auto currentWeight = m_hiddenNeurons[i].GetWeight(j);
                        m_hiddenNeurons[i].SetWeight(j,currentWeight + learningRate * deltaHidden[i] * m_hiddenNeurons[i].GetInput(j));
                    }
                    auto currentWeight = m_hiddenNeurons[i].GetBiasWeight();
                    m_hiddenNeurons[i].SetBiasWeight(currentWeight + learningRate * deltaHidden[i] * (1.0*currentWeight));
                }
            }
        }
    }

private:
    std::array<Neuron<NumInputs,sigmoid>,NumHidden()> m_hiddenNeurons;
    std::array<Neuron<NumHidden(),sigmoid>,NumOutputs> m_outputNeurons;
};

int main()
{

    NeuralNetwork<2,2> NN;

    std::vector<std::array<double,2>> trainingData = {{{0,1},{1,0},{1,1},{0,0}}};
    std::vector<std::array<double,2>> targetData = {{{1,0},{1,0},{0,1},{0,1}}};

    NN.Train(trainingData,targetData,0.03,100000);

    for(auto i = 0; i < trainingData.size(); ++i)
    {
        NN.PassForward(trainingData[i]);
        auto outputs = NN.GetOutputs();
        for(auto o = 0; o < outputs.size(); ++o)
        {
            std::cout << "Out " << o << ":\t" << outputs[o] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can it be you have an extra set of curly braces in the targetdata and trainingdata defintions? You try to declare a vector of arrays, but you initialize with the vector with a single value (the second set of curly braces).

Comment: `What is hopefully clear in the above is that for two of the problems given it; it sort of worked` -> Which of the 2 rows are the ones that worked? I expected in the first row to see `Expected 1` as `0` and `Expected 2` as `1` because `0 XOR 1 = 1` but that seems like I'm just misunderstanding your data. Care to explain it better? And what does a `0.4` in `NN Output 1` mean?

Comment: @MondKin think of the Outputs as the "will I output a 0" and "will I output a 1". So the expected results are the XOR results, Expected 1 meaning will it output 0 and Expected 2 meaning will it output 1. The actual NN outputs follow the same logic.

Comment: That I thought, but then your first case doesn't make sense to me: Inputs = 0 and 1, so the XOR should output a 1, but the `Expected 1` is `1` and `Expected 2` is `0`, shouldn't it be the other way around? Actually, the 4 test cases seem to be inverted

Comment: @MondKin XOR will only output a 1 if both inputs are the same, otherwise it will output a 0

Comment: Seems you have the concept inverted: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or  `a logical operation that outputs true only when inputs differ (one is true, the other is false)`

Comment: @MondKin I think you don't understand what I've written. It's correct. Expected 1 is FALSE, expected 2 is TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the same thing a few days ago, and I can tell you that 100 000 iterations for back propagation is not enough, if you hit some unfortunate weight initialization. Dont initialize you weights randomly, the sigmoid can easily fall into saturation for large weights, on the other hand 0 weights wont help either. I have initialized mine weights +/-(0.3, 0.7) and the convergence improved significantly.

Comment: I just updated the random range to be +-5.0 and that worked!